# Why does reversing an operation allow overflow handling?

Tags: java

A leetcode problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/description/) asks to reverse an integer, which is simple enough, but wants the user to return 0 if there is any overflow. Doing this with long is also simple, as you can check if it's greater than INTEGER.MAX_INT or MIN_INT in java. But if only 32 bit ints are allowed, how can this be accomplished?

The following solution is shown:

```
public int reverse(int x)
{
    int result = 0;

    while (x != 0)
    {
        int tail = x % 10;
        int newResult = result * 10 + tail;
        if ((newResult - tail) / 10 != result)
        { return 0; }
        result = newResult;
        x = x / 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm confused why this works. Why does "reversing" the operation, and comparing it to the previous result successfuly check for overflow?

If you started with x, then said:
x2 = (x*10) + b, wouldn't (x2-b)/10 *always* equal x? Since a positive overflow always loops around to the min value, and a negative overflow always loops around to the max value. How does this check for overflow? I would love any clarifications on this.

Comment: That's true for addition/subtraction, but not for multiplication.

Comment: Could you explain why that is? If the numbers are wrapping around like that, why isn't multiplication always the opposite of division when dealing with overflow?

Comment: Okay actually I think that makes sense. I went through some examples of smaller number systems, and when you multiply by a number and divide again, it is not equal. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you started with x, then said: x2 = (x*10) + b, wouldn't (x2-b)/10 always equal x?

No.  Your intuition about "looping" is correct for addition and subtraction - it's like moving back and forth on a clock face around 12 o'clock.

However, this doesn't apply to multiplication, as this example demonstrates:

```
int x = 2_000_000_000;
int y = x * 10;
int z = y / 10;

System.out.println(x);   // 2000000000
System.out.println(z);   // -147483648
```

[Live demo.](https://ideone.com/4Jpkk5)

So to answer the top-level question:

> Why does "reversing" the operation, and comparing it to the previous result successfully check for overflow?

Because when overflow occurs, "reversing" this sequence of operations won't get you back to the input value.

Comment: Can the concept of reversing a multiplication or division for an overflow be expanded to *any* multiplication or division operation? Or is it only valid in this case with a multiplication/division of 10? I ask because I saw very long solutions to this problem, and doing a reversal of operations sounds wayy easier, and I'm not sure why everyone is not doing this.